# How can I replace multiple values with one value into a new column?

Tags: python, pandas

There is a column in the dataset I am currently working on called Ground. The values in that column are the names of different cricket grounds all over the world. I want to create a new column in which the values must be the country names in which the grounds are located.
Below is the list of ground names.

```
array(['Auckland', 'Southampton', 'Johannesburg', 'Brisbane', 'Bristol',
       'Khulna', 'Wellington', 'Sydney', 'The Oval', 'Nairobi (Gym)',
       'Durban', 'Cape Town', 'Brabourne', 'Perth', 'Gqeberha',
       'Melbourne', 'Christchurch', 'Karachi', 'Manchester', 'Bridgetown',
       'Belfast', 'King City (NW)', 'Hamilton', 'Colombo (RPS)',
       'Port of Spain', 'Centurion', 'Dubai (DSC)', "Lord's",
       'Nottingham', 'Basseterre', 'Nagpur', 'Mohali', 'Colombo (PSS)',
       'Abu Dhabi', 'Hobart', 'Providence', 'Gros Islet', 'North Sound',
       'Lauderhill', 'Harare', 'Birmingham', 'Cardiff', 'Bloemfontein',
       'Kimberley', 'Adelaide', 'Pallekele', 'Mirpur', 'Eden Gardens',
       'Mombasa', 'ICCA Dubai', 'Hambantota', 'The Hague',
       'Chester-le-Street', 'Chennai', 'Pune', 'Wankhede', 'East London',
       'Bengaluru', 'Ahmedabad', 'Sharjah', 'Windhoek', 'Bulawayo',
       'Aberdeen', 'Kingstown', 'Rajkot', 'Chattogram', 'Kingston',
       'Sylhet', 'Roseau', 'Lahore', 'Bready', 'Edinburgh',
       'Dublin (Malahide)', 'Dharamsala', 'Cuttack', 'Mount Maunganui',
       'Ranchi', 'Visakhapatnam', 'Delhi', 'Napier', 'Kanpur', 'Geelong',
       'Greater Noida', 'Taunton', 'Guwahati', 'Potchefstroom',
       'Thiruvananthapuram', 'Indore', 'Nelson', 'Dehradun', 'Rotterdam',
       'Deventer', 'Amstelveen', 'Lucknow', 'Carrara', 'Al Amerat',
       'ICCA 2 Dubai', 'Canberra', 'Hyderabad', "St George's",
       'Rawalpindi', 'Paarl', 'Dunedin', 'Coolidge', 'Leeds', 'Dublin',
       'Jaipur', 'Tarouba'], dtype=object)
```

I did that one by one with another dataset. However, this dataset is huge.

Comment: I have to google the list of cricket grounds in each country.

Answer (score 1):

As starting point, you can use [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_cricket_grounds_by_capacity):

```
dfs = pd.read_html('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_cricket_grounds_by_capacity')
grounds = pd.concat(dfs)
```

Output:

```
>>> grounds[['Ground', 'City', 'Country']]

                                               Ground           City      Country
0                               Narendra Modi Stadium      Ahmedabad        India
1                            Melbourne Cricket Ground      Melbourne    Australia
2                                        Eden Gardens        Kolkata        India
3   Shaheed Veer Narayan Singh International Crick...         Raipur        India
4                                       Perth Stadium          Perth    Australia
..                                                ...            ...          ...
10                                     Sheffield Park       Uckfield      England
11                Vidarbha Cricket Association Ground         Nagpur        India
12                       Indira Priyadarshini Stadium  Visakhapatnam        India
13                            Queen Elizabeth II Park   Christchurch  New Zealand
14                                   Hyde Park Ground      Sheffield      England

[201 rows x 3 columns]
```

You can map on:

```
dmap = grounds.drop_duplicates('City').set_index('City')['Country']
df['Country'] = df['Ground'].str.extract('([^(]+)', expand=False).map(dmap)
print(df)

# Output
           Ground       Country
0        Auckland   New Zealand
1     Southampton       England
2    Johannesburg  South Africa
3        Brisbane     Australia
4         Bristol       England
..            ...           ...
103      Coolidge           NaN
104         Leeds       England
105        Dublin       Ireland
106        Jaipur         India
107       Tarouba           NaN

[108 rows x 2 columns]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use `df.replace` and use a dict for the `to_replace` argument that defines the mappings between cricket ground names and country names.